# Unable to show selected MVC Radio button

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I am working with a RadioButton group in ASP.NET, MVC, Razor and am trying to dynamically set the selected button on a radio group, based on the previously selected option.  Here is the pertinent code snippet:

```
List<Product> productList = ViewBag.ProductList;
    if (productList != null && productList.Count > 0)
    {
       foreach (Product product in productList)
       {
            <tr>
                 <td>
                  @Html.RadioButtonFor(p => p.ProductIdString, productList[i].Id, new { Checked = @ViewBag.ProductSelected==product.Id ? true: false, onclick="this.form.submit();", tabindex = @tab })
                  @{tab++;}
                  @{i++;}
                        <td>@product.Name</td>
                        <td>@product.Description</td>
                        <td>@product.FormattedPrice</td>
            </tr>
        }
}
```

During the first posting of the page, everything works as expected.  The saved productId correctly sets the option.  However, if a new option is selected after the initial load, then the selected button Checked and checked property and attributes will be correctly set as shown, but the previously selected button will be marked as checked on the form:

```
 <td>
    <input Checked="True" checked="checked" data-val="true" data-val-required="Please select a product" id="ProductIdString" name="ProductIdString" onclick="this.form.submit();" tabindex="30" type="radio" value="1" />
</td>
```

I have read quite a few posts that state that the Checked/checked attributes/properties are for the default selection and once set it appears that this cannot be changed?  Is this correct?  If not, how do you dynamically set the selected radio button?

Just one note, when the form is submitted to the controller the Request object has the correctly selected value, but it just doesn't display as selected.

I am at a loss here and would appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I would say first that he logic you have on the View should be resolved first in the Controller and be ready to be displayed when you pass it to the View in a viewbag or model.

To change the value of the radio you are going to need some javascript or to make it easier jQuery. Have a look at this arcticles:

https://api.jquery.com/change/

https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-check-uncheck-a-checkbox-input-or-radio-button/

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that it does not treat the html-attribute 'checked' in the right way.

The checked attribute is a boolean attribute! If the attribute is present, whatever it's content (true, false, checked, foobar), then the radiobutton is checked.

Because it's quite hard to have an optional html-attribute in Razor elements, i use this **trick**:

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(p => p.ProductIdString, productList[i].Id, 
Dictionary<string, object>() {
    {"checked" + (@ViewBag.ProductSelected==product.Id ? "": "not"), ""},
    {"onclick", "this.form.submit();"}, 
    {"tabindex", @tab} 
})
```

This way radiobutton elements have `checkednot` attribute when they are not selected, and `checked` when they are. The browser just ignores the checkednot attributes, and *only one* element is checked.